# online t-shirt printing - removing white from image upload

Tags: php, jquery, css, image, image-uploading

Some Background Info:
Basically I am looking to re-create a image upload onto a tshirt facility. This has been successful until the point where I need to remove the colour white from uploaded images to remove background colour. Flash is not an option im afraid, the upload facility script is written in PHP along with the use of jQuery drag to move and resize the images and test on the shirt.

A good example would be found at http://www.zazzle.co.uk where an option to "show whites in image as transparent" is available if you click on advanced options. I would like to imitate this feature however I am having problems figuring it out.

Any help would be great, just a point in the right direction? I have looked at using Jquery, PHP, ImageMagick but to no avail...

Comment: Try converting the image to PNG first.

Comment: Take a look at the PHP's GD Library: http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Answer (score 1):

ImageMagick can do it. Not sure why you've had no luck with that.

example ImageMagick command:

```
convert input.gif -transparent white output.gif
```

However, this will only work for pure white on the image. Not if it's slightly off white.

Comment: Thanks for that, I shall research ImageMagick further.

Answer (score 0):

Over at http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-invert-image-colors-tutorial/ and http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp you can take a look at some image manipulation in JavaScript. You could use that as a basis for your own routines.

What you do is to test if it is white (RGB = FF, FF, FF) and then set alpha to transparent (alpha = FF). You could also do some more advanced processing.